# Как отредактировать свойство при создании заказа?

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Всем привет !

Пытаюсь отредактировать свойство при создании заказа:

```
use Bitrix\Main; 
Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler(
    'sale',
    'OnSaleOrderBeforeSaved',
    'onBeforeOrderSaveHandler'
);

function onBeforeOrderSaveHandler(Main\Event $event)
{

    /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\Order $order */
    $order = $event->getParameter('ENTITY');
    $oldPrice = $order->getField('PRICE');
    $newval = CCurrencyRates::ConvertCurrency($oldPrice, "EUR", "RUB");
    $newPrice = round($newval);
    $propertyCode = 'new_price';

    /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue $property */
    foreach ($order->getPropertyCollection() as $property) {
        if ($property->getField('CODE') === $propertyCode) {
            $property->setValue($newPrice);
        }
    }

    $saveResult = $order->getPropertyCollection()->save();
}
```

Но при создании нового заказа получаю ошибку:
[image: console]

Новый заказ не создается, просто зависает в бесконечной загрузке. Ошибка в консоли ругается на эту функцию:

```
    function submitOrder(form) {
$('.js_ord').hide();
        $('#preloader').show();
        var pric = $("#price_delivery_id").val();
        if($("#deliveryTypesBlock .selected input[name='DELIVERY_ID']").data("ourdelivery") != 1){
          $("#price_delivery_id").val(0);
        }
        if($('[name="DELIVERY_ID"]:checked').val() == 2){

            $("#price_delivery_id").val(pric);
            $("input[name='ORDER_PROP_22']").val(pric)

        }
        var fname = $("input[name='ORDER_PROP_8']").val();
        var lname = $("input[name='ORDER_PROP_9']").val();
        var email = $("input[name='ORDER_PROP_2']").val();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/mailchump_integrate.php",
            data: { email: email, fname: fname, lname: lname }
        });

            var err=false;
            $('.pane.last').find('.pane-errors ul').empty()
            $('.pane').each(function(){
                var $pane = $(this);
                errors = validatePane($pane, "required")
                if(errors.length) {
                    for(var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; ++i) {
                        $('.pane.last').find('.pane-errors ul').append($("<li>" + errors[i] + "</li>"));
                        err =true;
                    }
                }
            })
            if(err)return false;
        $( '#price_delivery_id' ).val( 0 );
        var data = $(form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);

                 if(response['order']["REDIRECT_URL"]) {
                    location.href = response['order']["REDIRECT_URL"];
                 }

                var propertyErrors = response['order']["ERROR"]["PROPERTY"];

                if(propertyErrors) {
                    for(var i in propertyErrors) {
                        $('.errors ul').append($("<li>" + propertyErrors[i] + "</li>"))
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Подскажите в чем проблема ?

Comment: Ну, в самой ошибке написано, что свойство REDIRECT_URL прочитать не удалось. В response оно передаётся?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, может кому пригодится. В настройках модуля интернет-магазина нужно было включить обработку устаревших событий. После этого все заработало.